# Adding styles dynamically to element in vanilla js not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to customize the bar of an input of type range  but, for some reason I didn't figure out yet, the backgroundImage is not being set.

**What I am doing:**

```
var age = document.querySelector('#age');
var ageResult = document.querySelector('#age-result');
ageResult.textContent = age.value;
age.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    var value = (event.target.value - event.target.min) / (event.target.max - event.target.min);
    this.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, '
                                            + 'color-stop(' + value + ', #e8972c), '
                                            + 'color-stop(' + value + ', #e6e6e6) '
                                            + ')';
    if (event.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
        ageResult.textContent = event.target.value;
    }
})
```

**Here is the code snippet:**

```js
var age = document.querySelector('#age');
    age.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var value = (event.target.value - event.target.min) / (event.target.max - event.target.min);
        this.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, '
                                                + 'color-stop(' + value + ', #e8972c), '
                                                + 'color-stop(' + value + ', #e6e6e6) '
                                                + ')';
    })
```

```css
input[type=range]{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 /* fix for FF unable to apply focus style bug  */
 border: 1px solid white; 
}
input[type=range]:focus {
 outline: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
 background: #ccc;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 border: none;
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #ffffff;
 margin-top: -11px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
 height: 10px;
 background: #dddddd;
 border: none;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" name="age" id="age" min="14" max="70" value="31">
```

Can you see what I am doing wrong? Why does the style.backgroundImage isn't being set? I debugged and saw that it is empty right after that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what I was doing wrong..

I was forgetting to wrap inside url() and using this, instead event.target:

```
event.target.backgroundImage = 'url(-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, '
                                                + 'color-stop(' + value + ', #e8972c), '
                                                + 'color-stop(' + value + ', #e6e6e6) '
                                                + '))';
```

Comment: I think you want to set the `background` property, not `background-image`. The syntax you show here makes no sense.

Comment: why? it was supposed to be the background-image.. here is a working sample using jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/JnrvG/1/ @Tomalak

Comment: I don't care that it works. That only proves that the CSS parser is smarter than you. ;) Look at the documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.. the problem wasn't that..  :/

Answer (score 0):

Set your CSS properties in your CSS file. If you want to change something dynamically/programatically via a script (JavaScript) your best bet is to toggle a separate CSS class on/off to make the change.  In other words try and use JS's `.style` method as little as possible. Instead use JS's `.classList`.

Comment: I can't in this case.. I have to customize the bar while the user changes the range, so I am calculating the value of the backgroundImage dynamically

Comment: Do you have an idea why it isn't being set?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work for you.

```
var age = document.querySelector('#age');
    age.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
        var value = (event.target.value - event.target.min) / (event.target.max - event.target.min);
        this.style.backgroundImage = `-webkit-gradient(linear,center bottom,center top,from(green),color-stop(0.5, yellow),to(blue))`;
    })
```

So the problem is not with javascript but your webkit-gradient syntax.

Comment: It doesn't add the color to the range bar :/

Comment: Try on FireFox, which browser you are using??

Comment: I am testing it on chrome, but I did tryed it on FF and didn't work either (the value is now being set, but doesn't fill the bar as expected)